# Get people from Highrise by Highrise API, which have tags: tag1 OR tag2

Tags: highrise

I mean I need info of people from Highrise with tags: tag1 OR tag2

"OR" is very important.

For example:

```
GET people.xml?tag_id=2123123 //how i get people w tag1
GET people.xml?tag_id=5656622 //how i get people w tag2
```

but there are people, who have both tags and I don't what to duplicate them after merge to xml file.